# How to increase XfceWindowMenuPlugin::max-width-chars and XfceTasklist::menu-max-width-chars in xfce 4.14?

Tags: xfce, xfce4

I am running xfce 4.14 in debian 10.

The default size of `xfdesktop -W`, Panel window grouping, and Panel window menu plugin are too small. I can not see the entire path.

I checked the official doc https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/windowmenu and https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/tasklist

I did add their code to `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and even `~/.gtk-2.0/gtkrc` and modifies to

```
XfceWindowMenuPlugin::max-width-chars = 1000
XfceTasklist::menu-max-width-chars = 1000
```

And then run `xfce4-panel -r` or even logout and relogin, and even reboot. It just doesn't work at all.

I don't know if I am wrong or the official doc is wrong.

**Edited:**

I found a good alternative tool which is `rofi`. (https://github.com/davatorium/rofi).

Just introduce it to anyone who failed to increase the width.